# regex to find content from occurrance of word and not including the word until a char

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
my-value=dingdong.example.org;another-value=a1.2xscf;generated-at=lala.example.com;orig-val=blahblah
```

and am trying to figure out how to capture just the values of the variable names.

I.e. if I search for string `my-value`, I want the output to return everything after the `=` and up to the `;`.

In the above example this should output:

```
dingdong.example.org
```

The following regex

```
(.*?my-value=.*?);
```

gets the string I am looking for, but I've not figured out how to split after the `=`.

Comment: *Why is your code invisible?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the opening parentheses after the `=` instead of the beginning of the pattern and you'll the value in the first capture group:

```
.*?my-value=(.*?);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LtCnpI/1